# wxListCtrl not displaying properly

Tags: python, wxpython

Help!

I am a non-GUI programmer who is trying to write a simple (!) program using wxPython.

I have read everything I can online, but my overall lack of GUI experience is presumably causing me to not see the problem.

In a nutshell, I want to have a window with a wxNotebook with several tabs.  Each tab, of course, will have its own child widgets.   I envision having either a wxListCtrl (as in my code) or possibly a wxGrid control, along with several buttons.

Here is my "EmployeesPanel" class.  When I run this, I see a tiny square that must represent the listctrl, but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to make it look correct.  Of course, it is possible that I am way off base in some other area(s) as well.

Any help as to what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
import wx
import sys

employees = [('Earl Boffo', 'Software'), ('Mildred Plotka', 'Software'), ('Sugar Kane', 'QA')]

classes = [('Python'), ('Java'), ('C#')]

class EmployeesPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        # create some sizers 
        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        grid = wx.GridBagSizer(hgap=5, vgap=5)

        #hSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL|wx.EXPAND)
        hSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        self.list = wx.ListCtrl(panel, size=(100,100), style=wx.LC_REPORT)

        self.list.InsertColumn(0, 'Name')
        self.list.InsertColumn(1, 'Group')

        for i in employees:
            index = self.list.InsertStringItem(sys.maxint, i[0])
            self.list.SetStringItem(index, 1, i[1])

        # A button
        self.button = wx.Button(self, label="Exit")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick,self.button)
        self.list.Show(True)

        # add the listctrl widget to the grid
        grid.Add(self.list, pos=(0,0), flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL)

        # add the button to the grid
        grid.Add(self.button, pos=(1,0))

        # add a spacer to the sizer
        grid.Add((10, 40), pos=(1,1))

        # add grid to hSizer
        hSizer.Add(grid, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        # add hSizer to main (v) sizer
        mainSizer.Add(hSizer, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(mainSizer)
        self.Show()

    def EvtComboBox(self, event):
        self.logger.AppendText('EvtComboBox: %s\n' % event.GetString())
    def OnClick(self,event):
        sys.exit(3)

app = wx.App(False)
frame = wx.Frame(None, title="Training Tracker", size=(700,500))
nb = wx.Notebook(frame)

nb.AddPage(EmployeesPanel(nb), "Employees")
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: What happens if you add the line `self.Layout()`  after `self.SetSizerAndFit()`? This is usually the first thing I try when trouble shooting wxPython. It forces the sizes of everything to be recalculated. Additionally, what if you only call 'self.SetSizer()` instead of `self.SetSizerAndFit()`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Neither of those changed the behavior at all.    I may try the same example, but with a Grid control to see how it changes, if at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to wxPython! It's actually a lot of fun once you get the hang of it. I almost never use the grid sizers as they're just a pain for simple layouts like this. If you have a grid like interface and you don't have controls that are going to stretch across cells, then it's great. Otherwise, I almost always use BoxSizers nested in each other. I simplified your code quite a bit to show the two widgets. Currently the list control only stretches horizontally. If you need it to go vertically too, then change the proportion from 0 to 1 in the sizer.Add part.

```
import wx
import sys

employees = [('Earl Boffo', 'Software'), ('Mildred Plotka', 'Software'), ('Sugar Kane', 'QA')]

classes = [('Python'), ('Java'), ('C#')]

class EmployeesPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        # create some sizers 
        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.list = wx.ListCtrl(self, size=(100,100), style=wx.LC_REPORT)

        self.list.InsertColumn(0, 'Name')
        self.list.InsertColumn(1, 'Group')

        for i in employees:
            index = self.list.InsertStringItem(sys.maxint, i[0])
            self.list.SetStringItem(index, 1, i[1])

        # A button
        self.button = wx.Button(self, label="Exit")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick,self.button)

        mainSizer.Add(self.list, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 5)
        mainSizer.Add(self.button, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.SetSizer(mainSizer)
        self.Show()

    def EvtComboBox(self, event):
        self.logger.AppendText('EvtComboBox: %s\n' % event.GetString())
    def OnClick(self,event):
        sys.exit(3)

app = wx.App(False)
frame = wx.Frame(None, title="Training Tracker", size=(700,500))
nb = wx.Notebook(frame)

nb.AddPage(EmployeesPanel(nb), "Employees")
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

I also think these articles might help you:

- wxPython: [wx.ListCtrl Tips and Tricks](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/01/04/wxpython-wx-listctrl-tips-and-tricks/)
- wxPython: [Using ObjectListView instead of a ListCtrl](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/12/23/wxpython-using-objectlistview-instead-of-a-listctrl/)
- http://wiki.wxpython.org/ListControls

Comment: Wow, thanks, Mike!  I will certainly study this code.  As a mostly embedded systems programmer, I haven't done much UI programming, so this will help quite a bit.  I love the idea of being platform independent with Python!